# Why SQLSTATE doesn't work?

Tags: mysql

I need to check the number of reputation for each user before inserting his vote. So for that purpose, I have a `TRIGGER` like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_reputation BEFORE INSERT ON votes
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF(new.user_id < 50) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot vote";
      END IF;
    END;
```

But it doesn't work, and here is the error:

[image]

Well, what's the problem? How can I check `SQLSTATE '45000' TEXT_MESSAGE` works on my current version or not?

**Note:** I use of MySQL 5.0.67

[image]

Comment: Where is `Delimitier`?

Comment: I don't think the problem be `Delimitier`. Because I use `//` in the first and end of that.

Comment: Do you have `vote` table? See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3975af)

Comment: `Votes` and yes. I think the problem is related to the version. How can I check it?

Comment: @lad2025 Then I'm almost sure that the problem is MySQL version. MySQL 5.0.67 doesn't support `SQLSTATE` ? How can I check it?

Comment: We don't see the delimiter in your example, and your trigger definition ends with `;`.

Please double check the delimiter.

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr I did it again. Please check MySQL version for me.. Or tell me how can I check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signal was introduced in MySQL 5.5. See [What Is New in MySQL 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-nutshell.html)

Comment: Correct. From what I am reading, you can't use signal in 5.0.67